# reverseGeocode does not come back to its call back when called from another function.

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function to get location details from google API's reverseGeocode function like below.

```js
var getLocationDetails = function (callback, latLng) {
 console.log("Getting location details using Google API" + latLng.lat + latLng.lng);
 var locationDetails = {};
 googleMapsClient.reverseGeocode({
  latlng: [parseFloat(latLng.lat),parseFloat(latLng.lng)]
 }, function(err, response) {
  if (!err) {
   locationDetails.address = response.json.results[0].formatted_address ;
   locationDetails.locality = response.json.results[1].address_components[2].long_name;
   locationDetails.area = response.json.results[1].address_components[3].long_name;
   locationDetails.state = response.json.results[1].address_components[4].long_name;
   locationDetails.country = response.json.results[1].address_components[5].long_name;
   locationDetails.zipCode = response.json.results[1].address_components[6].long_name;
   console.log("Fetched location is " + locationDetails.address);   
   callback(err,locationDetails);
  } else {
   callback(err,locationDetails);
  }
 });
 console.log("blah blah");
};
```

When I call this function like below, execution quietly come to the line "console.log("blah blah");". But when I call just the googleMapsClient.reverseGeocode(), it goes to the callback inside reverseGeocode and prints all the locationDetails. Why doesn't execution come to the function(err, response) after reverGeocode() is finished.

```js
loc.getLocationDetails( function(err, locationDetails) {
       if (!err) {
        //console.log(response.json.results[1].address_components);
        console.log(locationDetails.address);
              } else {
                console.log("could not fetch location details");
                }
}
```